# Kalman filter F matrix for mpu6050

Tags: filter, arduino, kalman-filter, mpu6050

So i have been trying to study the kalman filter for mpu6050. I used library from [here](http://tkjelectronics/lauszus%20http://blog.tkjelectronics.dk/2012/09/a-practical-approach-to-kalman-filter-and-how-to-implement-it/#comment-57783) it was made by tkjelectronics/lauszus. I already understand the "big" line of the library itself and already implement it. But i still have no idea why he came across to use F matrix like this :
[image]

can someone explain to me why? i have tried to google around but i havent found anything that provide me with information i have been trying to seek. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Briefly, the Kalman filter algorithm consists of a prediction step and an update step. The prediction step estimates the current state of the system from the previous state. The update step updates/corrects the predicted state by using the next measurements observed.

The F matrix, also called state transition matrix, is used in prediction step. The form of F matrix depends on the motion model of the system.

Among many good resources, you may check the following to know more on
[How Kalman filter works](http://www.bzarg.com/p/how-a-kalman-filter-works-in-pictures/)

and
[How to implement Kalman filter](https://medium.com/@mithi/object-tracking-and-fusing-sensor-measurements-using-the-extended-kalman-filter-algorithm-part-1-f2158ef1e4f0)

You may use the following python libraries to implement

1. [filterpy](https://github.com/rlabbe/filterpy)
2. [pykalman](https://github.com/pykalman/pykalman)

Good luck.